# How to connect kali linux to a wifi using WPA2 Enterprise, using PEAP method?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, authentication, wpa, wpa2-eap

I am using Kali Linux 2019.4, kernel version 5.3.0-kali2-amd64 and I have trouble connecting to my school wifi, which uses WPA2 Enterprise and uses PEAP (Protected Extensible Authentication Protocol).

I tried to connect with correct credentials but it showed that Linux can't scan the access point and I cannot connect to the wifi. The IT department in my school told me to use Ubuntu instead but I do not want to do that unless it is the only way.

Comment: Try to get some **wpa_supplicant** logs: `journalctl -u wpa_supplicant`.

Comment: I do not have the logs from the time when I attempted to connect to the wifi. What should I do next?

Comment: You can also look in `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/messages` (search for `wpa_supplicant` or your wireless interface name). `systemd-journald` by default keeps logs in `/run`. You can persist them creating a directory `/var/log/journal` and issuing `journalctl --flush`

Comment: I found the source of the problem. The problem is that my school uses PEAP 5 and kali only supports PEAP 1 or 0. I need to make it support PEAP 5. Any idea how?

Comment: There is no PEAP 5.

Comment: I mean PEAP version 5

Comment: PEAP versioning stops v2. The only related acronym that contains a 5 is MD5, which is disabled in most current distributions.

Comment: My IT department told me that their peap version is 5 or something. It could be 2.5. I am using ubuntu alongside kali to use wifi at school. I think that this thread could be closed.